# how to select first row from each id in a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table - 1st table as "estate_infos" and 2nd table as "img_info" .

And i store the id of "estate_infos" in "img_info" as "estate_infos_id" which is a foreign key id as shown below-
[screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPiV7.png)

I want to select the yellow marked row from each "estate_infos_id" which is first row of each "estate_infos_id" .
So, How can i achieve that?

ps: my mysql version is 7.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables and then make a sub select join where you take out the smallest img_id (first row) for each estate_infos, then join on that:

```
SELECT i.*, e.*
FROM estate_infos e
join img_info i ON i.estate_infos_id = e.id
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(img_id) img_id, estate_infos_id FROM img_info GROUP BY estate_infos_id
) m
WHERE i.img_id = m.img_id
```

Then just change the select to the actual fields you need.